# Video analysis frame by frame without decompressing the video file

Tags: c#, video-processing, emgucv

I am using **EMGU.CV** for a vehicle counting project.

---

The capture method of Capture.cs can take the video file name as argument and process the video, frame by frame. The vehicle counting, which is based on background subtraction and moving object detection, is working fine.

**Problem:**

Capture method only can read a raw formatted (fully decompressed) file. Where I have **173mb video footage of 1 hour** to analyze, if I **convert it in RAW format with original specs (720*480 px & 29.7 fps)** the converted file size increases to **~50 GB**.

**173 MB file after Raw conversion ~50 GB.** Which is too expensive for me.

But no other encodings are supported in EMGU.CV to analyze frame by frame (as far I know). But there are several solutions on vehicle counting, which don't need extra memory.

**Are there any processes regarding emgu.cv capture or any other process to analyse a compressed video frame by frame?**

Comment: Can you convert sections of the video to work on? (You didn't say what you are using to decompress it.)

Comment: I am using ffmpeg to decompress it. I have splitted a 24 hours video in 5 mins segment (means in 288 files) and convert them 1 or 2 or 4 files at a time (so that the total disk space remain relatively low ) using parallel programming, and after processing of converted file I delete the converted files and again convert and process nexr 1 or 2 or 4 files. 
But this process creates several problem. This looks odd, disk space is a little problem yet and the most dangerous thing, I have to deal with several unmanage codes and dlls, In result, often it crushes blaming ntdll.dll.

Comment: It looks like you can interact with the FFmpeg dlls from your program using a wrapper: [Invoke FFmpeg to export frames](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/893611/Invoke-FFmpeg-to-export-frames).

Comment: but only extracting to frames will not work. I have to trigger an event while frame is change. And I can extract all frames and process them using various architecture, but the memory problem remains a little (700 mb files after extracting in jpeg will take 3-4 gb) and the process becomes two times slower.

Comment: I was thinking of decompressing into RAM: 5 minutes of video might take 180 MB. You then run your vehicle counting on that segment and never write decompressed video to disk. Of course, that might not be possible, but if it is it should be somewhat faster.

Comment: 5 mins of video (720 * 480 px & 29.7fps) takes 800 MB - 1 GB after fully decompressing to RAW format.  And processing 5 mins file each is not the best solution I think. I have to find out a way not to decompress the full file OR decompress on the fly.

Comment: I gave some wrong information mistakenly, you can check it in question @AndrewMorton